# Uploading data to RedShift using COPY

Tags: copy, delimiter, amazon-redshift

I am trying to upload data to RedShift using COPY command.

On this row:
4072462|10013868|default|2015-10-14 21:23:18.0|0|'A=0

I am getting this error:
Delimited value missing end quote

This is the COPY command:
copy test
from 's3://test/test.gz'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=xxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxx' removequotes escape gzip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I hope you know why you are getting the mentioned error: You have a a single quote in one of the column values. While using the `removequotes` option, Redshift [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-removequotes) clearly says that:

> If a string has a beginning single or double quotation mark but no corresponding ending mark, the COPY command fails to load that row and returns an error.

One thing is certain: `removequotes` is certainly not what you are looking for.

Second, so what are your options?

1. If preprocessing the S3 file is in your control, consider using the `escape` option. Per the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-escape),

> When this parameter is specified, the backslash character (\) in input data is treated as an escape character.

So your input row in S3 should change to something like:

> 4072462|10013868|default|2015-10-14 21:23:18.0|0|\'A=0

2. See if the `CSV DELIMITER '|'` works for you. Check documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-format.html#copy-csv).

Comment: Thanks @ketan, eventually I solved it by double quoting all my values. I have another issue: I have values with new lines. Any way RedShift can handle that?

Comment: can you try using 'escape' along with a backslash just before the newline character?